# System.Messaging.MessageQueueException- External component has thrown an exception

Tags: c#, queue, message-queue, msmq, msmq-transaction

I run .exe through windows service which reads the message from Private Queue. The service is all good and stable but at times the service stops (it actually does not stop, but it is not processing anything. Service status is still "Started", I need to manually restart it).

This one doesn't show up often but analyzing the memory dump of the .exe file, I found that so many threads encountered below exception.

> Exception object: 0000000001436120 
>   Exception type: System.Messaging.MessageQueueException 
>   Message: External component has
>   thrown an exception.

```
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException- External component has thrown an exception
System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(System.TimeSpan, Int32, System.Messaging.Interop.CursorHandle, System.Messaging.MessagePropertyFilter, System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransaction, System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransactionType) 
System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Peek(System.TimeSpan)
```

Any idea why service encounters this exception?? Thanks in advance